# PayPal: image_url versus cpp_header_image

Tags: paypal

What is the difference between "image_url" and "cpp_header_image" html variables used in customizing the PayPal pages. On PayPal website, I could not understand where these images will be shown. it says top/left and upper/left and the words top/upper confusing to me.

Comment: Please add a link to the page you are quoting the top/left and upper/left text from.

Comment: Link is [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B).

Answer (score 1):

There are two version of PayPal checkout - "classic" and "enhanced".  Enhanced is the new version that they started rolling out ~18 months ago.

Some sellers will send all their customers to classic, some will send all their customers to enhanced, and some are (or at least were) in an A/B test between the two.

The "enhanced" version seems to be more common now.  It's the one where on the left hand side of the PayPal page there is a rounded corner box with a color gradient border.  The sellers logo goes **inside** this box.

In the "classic" version the seller had the entire top strip of the page in which to put their logo.

I believe that cpp_header_image refers to PayPal "classic" and image_url is for "enhanced".

THat said - unless you really need per request control over your logos it is much much easier to configure this by logging in to your seller account and editing your "custom page styles".